# How to save txt files on a network drive?

Tags: c++, networking, fstream, lan

I am a +2 student from India. And I am looking forward to create a LAN chat program in C++ for the project in our school.

I have learnt the basics of C++ including the basics of fstream.h
I would therefore like to get answers in a simple form.

I would like to know if I can save a txt file created using fstream in a network drive and access it on other computers simultaneously. And is it possible to update the txt file every second? I would also like to know how to do so if possible.

Thanks all for your answers....

Comment: The operating system makes network drives look just like local files. Just use the correct pathname for the network drive.

Comment: Sure - just make sure you can see the path to the file from a shell/prompt and give the full path when you open the file.

Comment: FYI, there is no `fstream.h` in modern C++, it is now `fstream`.

Comment: "access it on other computers simultaneously." This depends on the rules of the file sharing protocol and the operating system. The file may be locked to prevent simultaneous access.

Comment: The basic answer to your question is yes, but I think you need to edit your question to add a few more details or this question is at risk of being closed as too broad. For example, we do not know if is there a single writer with many readers or if all all the users can modify the file. The second option would be far more complicated.

Comment: Using a shared file is probably not the right way to do a chat client.

Comment: I would use sockets for that. There will be 1000s or examples from a google search.

Comment: @user4581301 I would consider making this program so add all users can modify the file.  But if it is so difficult I would make it the other way...